# Single Quote Issue While Filtering Records In SpGridview

Tags: filter, spgridview, single-sign-on

In SpGridview single quote is breaking the filter expression as we are having filter format as **"{1} like '{0}'"**,any idea how we can handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the OnPreRender method to escape the single quotes:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_gridDS.FilterExpression))
    {
        _gridDS.FilterExpression = string.Format(
            _grid.FilteredDataSourcePropertyFormat,
            _grid.FilterFieldValue.Replace("'", "''"),
            _grid.FilterFieldName);
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

You can check out the full blog post here: [SharePoint’s SPGridView, filtering, and apostrophes](http://kitmenke.com/blog/2009/09/05/sharepoints-spgridview-filtering-and-apostrophes/) (full disclosure, this is my blog).

You can also check out a similar question on StackOverflow: [SPGridView, data and correct method of ensuring data is safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351578/spgridview-data-and-correct-method-of-ensuring-data-is-safe)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using ‘=’ instead of ‘LIKE’ as filtering columns with number values (SPField of type Integer or Number) throws exception. ‘=’ in SQL can be used for text as well as for number 
comparisons.
Give it a try.